# When using the Real Name module, how can I show the original (raw) username in a view?

Tags: views, users

The [Real Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname) module allows a field in the user profile to be displayed as a user's name instead of the user name set upon registration.

This works great for my site as it allows people to set nicknames without having to worry about them being unique, etc.

However, I want to create a view for administrators that lists the actual (raw) username, not the real name.  When I add a **User: Name** field in views, though, the real name is displayed, and I don't see any option for the raw result.

How can I show the raw result in Views when Real Name is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in using the field `User: Name` as there is no explicit Raw name field (only a token). Now in the field settings you must uncheck `Link this field to its user` and `More > Use formatted username`.

If you still want to have a link to the user's profile, do some field rewriting: add `User: uid`, move it above `User: Name`, check `Rewrite results > Output this field as a link` with the path `user/[uid]` or `user/[uid]/edit`.